# Use variable/parameter as array identifier

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I enter the array identifiers manually it will work, however using the parameters in the function it won't work. I know where the problem is, but not what I can replace ".key" with, so that it'll use the parameters value.

```
var stuff = [
 { "name": "Alex", "food": "Pizza"},
 { "name": "Karl", "food": "Lasagne"},
 { "name": "Franz", "food": "Potato salad"}
]

function getSpecificValue(key, value, getkey, arr) {
    for (var i=arr.length;i--;) {
        if (arr[i].key == value) { //this should use the parameter "key" ("name")
            return arr[i].getkey; //this should use the parameter "getkey" ("food")
        }
    }
}

alert( getSpecificValue('name', 'Alex', 'food', stuff) ); //alert "Pizza"
```

Comment: You're looking for "bracket notation", see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: okay, got it `if (arr[i][key] == value) {
            return arr[i][getkey];
        }`Thanks, I would accept your answer, if it wouldn't be a comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always access object properties using "bracket" or "array" notation:

```
for (var i=arr.length;i--;) {
    if (arr[i][key] == value) { //this should use the parameter "key" ("name")
        return arr[i][getkey]; //this should use the parameter "getkey" ("food")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) @elclanrs comment already provided me with what I was looking for. But I'll accept your answer for anyone who may stumble upon this page.